# Creating an Admin- Official Doc

Tags: sonata-admin

I'm trying to learn Sonata and I started to follow the official doc. I created a docker project with symfony 3.4, then I add the admin bundle. There is something that making me crazy from days. I will explain the best I can:

- 1 step -> Docker with containers
- 2 step -> skeleton of Symfony 3.4
- 3 step -> Starting sonata [official doc](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/getting_started/installation.html). At the end I should see the admin page but no way, nothing
- 4 step -> I put everything on git, I delete everything, I clone the project, composer install and the magic, I have the admin page.....Why???:(
- 5 step -> I continue with doc to create an admin; at the end I should see the page admin with Category, Add new, List but nothing. If I do the same procedure as before (deleting folder, clone the project with my last changes, composer), I can see the new changes in the admin page. So what's wrong?
  Could you help me to understand?

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you need some informations more to help me, just ask me. Basically there no other php code than the guided code. Thanks again

Comment: Hello guys, finally I found the problem in the app.php file:
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false); -> $kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);

Now the command cache:clear woks fine.